# .htaccess ignoring RewriteCond

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following directory structure for a site we're currently working on:

```
root
   - admin/
   - assets/
   - cache/
   - images/
   - .htaccess
   - category.php
   - image.php
   - resize.php
```

I would like to rewrite the URLs according to a number of conditions, and have achieved this using `.htaccess`. For some reason, Apache seems to be completely ignoring the `RewriteCond` rules I have added. Here's a copy of the `.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php category.php
Options +FollowSymLinks 

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Image rewrites:
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ resize.php?function=resizeRatio&width=$2&src=images/$1/$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)([0-9]+)/(.*)$ resize.php?function=resizeRatio&width=$3&src=images/$1/$2/$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)/(.*)$ resize.php?function=resizeCrop&width=$2&height=$3&src=images/$1/$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)/(.*)$ resize.php?function=resizeCrop&width=$3&height=$4&src=images/$1/$2/$5 [L]

# Category rewrites:
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ category.php?parent=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ category.php?parent=$1&child=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+).(.*)$ image.php?image=$2.$3&parent=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+).(.*)$ image.php?image=$3.$4&parent=$1&child=$2 [L]
```

When attempting to visit `/admin/`, I am directed to the rewritten page of `category.php?category=admin/`.

Why is Apache behaving in this manner, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: You are aware that RewriteConds only apply to the one RewriteRule that directly follows them …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteCond` is only applicable to very next `RewriteRule`.

Replace your `RewriteCond` lines with this:

```
## If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
## If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

This will avoid rest of `RewriteRule` lines for a valid file, directory or link.